# Background size on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, background-image

I've spent the morning doing research on the following issue. I'm making a one page site,  using a lot of images. I'm aware that Safari is known for its weird handling of background-attachment:fixed, but that's working fine; my problem is `background-size:cover` is not working in conjunction with `fixed`.

I have 5 pages, all of which have a `height` or `min-height` of 100%. The last page is fixed like this:

```
#div5 {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
  background-attachment:fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

On iOS (in both Chrome and Safari) the background image is scaled to cover the full webpage, so it's really stretched.

At the same time, page 4 has the following css:

```
#div4 {
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:url(img/portfoliobg.jpg);
  overflow: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and this works like a charm.

So, something makes the browser behave really weirdly when combining `fixed` and `cover`. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: When testing on Safari and Chrome on Windows, does it work as expected?

Comment: yes it does exactly what I want. chrome on android works fine too

Comment: @Merijndk do you have any information on what version iOS?

Answer (score 5):

Use another div with `position:fixed` to make the background fixed.

Like this: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVebNg

JADE

```
.fixed
  .bgcover
```

SCSS

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  .bgcover {
      background-image: url('http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/winter/winter-04.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can’t (for now).

You can play with `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}` but for now iPad Pro have resolution more then ordinary monitors.

I offer you to disable fixed attachment for mobiles via this way:

Main CSS file:

```
.parallax {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Main HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android|Silk)/gi)) {
      document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"fixparallax.css\" />");
   }
</script>
```

Additional **fixparallax.css**

```
.parallax {
   background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```