# Background image blurry on some pages on iOs

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, background-image, mobile-safari

I have a website http://basement-recordings.com/ built with wordpress and I have a problem with the background image: on iOs, on some of the pages (for example Entertainment & Events) the background image looks blurry, unclear. This happens on both Chrome and Safari.

I have looked for a solution but I cannot seem to find anything. Can anyone please help me?

[image: Good quality] [image: Poor quality]

Comment: Have you got background-size set anywhere in the css?

Comment: @Callam Yes background-size is set to cover, but as far as I can figure it out the problem is background-attachment: fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS has an issue preventing background-position: fixed from being used with background-size: cover

See http://caniuse.com/#search=background-attach *Known Issues and

[Background size on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476380/background-size-on-ios)