# image is flikering on scroll on mobile devices

Tags: css, html

```css
body{

background-color: #000;

height: 100vh;

}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#bubbles1, #bubbles2{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;

z-index: -1;
}

#bubbles1{
  background: url('img/greencat.png') 60% 50% no-repeat fixed;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  
 
}

#bubbles2{
background: url('img/catb.png') 60% 50%  no-repeat fixed;

position: fixed;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}

#fish{

background: transparent url('img/textgreen.png') no-repeat bottom left fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
#fish1{

background: transparent url('img/textblue.png') no-repeat bottom left fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   /* position: absolute;*/
    top: 0px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 860px){


ound-image: url('img/greencat-mobile.png');
    background-size: 250vw 100vh;
    background-position: 53% 50%;
  }

  #bubbles2{
    background-image: url('img/catb-mobile.png');
 
    background-size: 250vw 100vh;
    background-position: 53% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

  }
  #fish{
    background: transparent url('http://www.intomorrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Barnsley-House-Spa-2-844x800.jpg') no-repeat 3% 78% fixed;
    position: absolute;
   }
  #fish1{
    background: transparent url('http://www.intomorrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Fairmont-Pittsburgh-30-844x800.jpg') no-repeat 3% 78% fixed;
  }


}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <div id="bubbles1"></div>
  <div id="fish"></div>
</section>
<section id="section2">
  <div id="bubbles2"></div>
  <div id="fish1"></div>
</section>
```

*This is my html and css, the problem is when i scroll on mobile devices than image is flikering, not stick to the fixed position. I gave the position fixed in css but it is not working. I checked on Android, Windows and Apple devices.
Android : first image moved up on scrolling
Windows : first image displaying proper but when i scroll for second image than its flikering
Apple : display white background insted of image, second image visible but its flikering on scroll*

Comment: did u try using img tag?

Comment: @3bu1 yeah i tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

> Most mobile devices have a delay in updating the background position after scrolling a page with fixed backgrounds.

i came across this problem too. 
i know 3 possible fixes for this

**1.** you can try using a pseudo-element and add background fixed to it

**2.** you can make another div inside the fixed div. and add background to that div

**3.** use `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0x); transform:translateZ(0)` to force hardware acceleration

see more here

- http://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment
- [Background size on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476380/background-size-on-ios)

let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i cannot find the solution of my question