# background-attachment: fixed does not work in Safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, parallax

I have a div with a `background-attachment: fixed` CSS style to achieve a parallax effect which works perfectly in chrome but does not work in Safari. It causes extreme jittering when scrolling past in Safari, so much so that it is not possible to leave as is. When I comment out this CSS property the jittering is stopped (which highlights the problem is this specific styling property).  I have looked at other posts on this but have yet to find something that fixes this behaviour or provides a workaround.

CSS:

```
#gallery {
  background: url("../images/parallax-image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top right;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 45vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS has an issue preventing background-attachment: fixed from being used with background-size: cover. from "Can I Use".

could check on Can I Use tab "Known issues".

https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

and fine details link

[Background size on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476380/background-size-on-ios)

maybe "background-size: 100% 100%;" could help.

or use other div background like below.

sorry i don't has ios could check it work.

```css
    body{
      height: 200vh;
    }
    .container{
      position: relative;
      height: 1920px;
    }
    .bgc{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random=1');
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bgc">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this does not work since background-attachment: fixed; gives unexpected behaviour in safari